# Question about Definition of homeomorphism (counter example)

Tags: general-topology

I'm teaching my self topology with the aid of a book, but i'm confused about the meaning of homeomorphic. Below, I have 2 topologies, $\mathscr{T}_1$ and $\mathscr{T}_2$ and I'm pretty sure they are not homeomorphic, but I can make a continuous bijection between them.

Definition of homeomorphism:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ is a bijective map $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ such that both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are continuous.

Definition of continuous:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be continuous if for every open subset $U \subseteq Y$, its preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

my (counter) example:

Let: $X = \{ 1,2,3 \}$

$\mathscr{T}_1=\{X,\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$;

$\mathscr{T}_2=\{X,\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}$;

$ g: \mathscr{T}_1 \rightarrow \mathscr{T}_2$

$g$ is defined by the table below:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 V & g(V) \\ \hline \hline
 X & X \\ \hline
 \varnothing & \varnothing \\ \hline
 \{1\} & \{1\} \\ \hline
 \{1,2\} & \{1,2\} \\ \hline
 \{2\} & \{1,3\} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Then $g^{-1}$ would be:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 U & g^{-1}(U) \\ \hline \hline
 X & X \\ \hline
 \varnothing & \varnothing \\ \hline
 \{1\} & \{1\} \\ \hline
 \{1,2\} & \{1,2\} \\ \hline
 \{1,3\} & \{2\} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The space is discrete so all sets are open (and closed). My book says that "size" is not a topological property, so it seems okay to map {2} to {1,3}.

So, it seems to me that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous and bijective, so the topologies are homeomorphic.

I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong, and I have another similar example like this. Please help me understand to meaning of homeomorphic.

note: I **Do** understand why a line segment and a circle are not homeopathic, when there are two topological spaces generated by different metrics (on the same set), by showing there are sets that are open in one space but not the other. But in this example everything is open, so wouldn't all bijections be continuous in a discrete space?

Comment: There are two concepts need to clarify, I guess.

1.function.

2.set function.

In the definition of continuous, $f$ means the set function of the function $f$.

They use the same symbol $f$.

Comment: Are you saying my $g$ is not a proper "set function," If so what would be an example of a proper (set) function in this case?

Comment: Excuse me, can you please explain what is "proper" you describe here?

Comment: I just made a follow up post, in it I wrote what I now think is as "proper" function. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839880/verify-if-this-is-correct-idea-of-continuous-and-homeomorphism

Comment: I think you are right in the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like par said, the mapping is supposed to be on the underlying sets themselves.  When we have a continuous function $g: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, the function sends points in the set $X$ to points in in the set $Y$.  Notice that if $\{2\}$ is being mapped to $\{1,3\}$, then 2 is mapped to 1 and 3 which can't even happen with a function.  Your function is still a bijection between the two topologies but not the sets $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks, If the spaces are $(X,\mathscr{T}_1)$  and $(X,\mathscr{T}_2)$. Then couldn't the map simply be the identity map, since they both use the same set?

Comment: If that was the case, then for example the inverse of {1,3} would still be {1,3}, but {1,3} is not open in the first topology.  Basically two spaces are homeomorphic if they are really the same space only represented differently.  It's like how a group isomorphism is a map between two groups that are actually the same group only represented with different symbols.  The two topological spaces you have defined are not homeomorphic.  You have one of them have two one point sets and the other having only one.

Comment: (1) You said {1,3} is not open, but I thought in a discrete space all sets are both open and closed (2) I know the example is not really an isomorphism , but it seems like they fit the given definition.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky when we say a discrete space we mean a set endowed with the topology being the power set of that set.  Neither of the topologies you have mentioned are the power set of X, so they are not discrete spaces.  But I know how it can get confusing because yeah, X is a finite set which can also mean discrete.  Either way, a discrete space is one where every subset of the underlying set is open.

Comment: So is {1,3} not open in the first topology because its not one of the open sets listed in it?

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky that is correct!

Comment: I think I'm finally getting this! If there is not a metric than "openness" is defined by the sets listed in the topology. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky let me also add that there are multiple ways in which one can define a topology in a given set X.  Topology started roughly as a means to formalize the concepts of "nearness" or "arbitrary closeness" among many other things.  It was first motivated by understanding how to study such concepts in real space like $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$, but they generalized these concepts to arbitrary sets or spaces.

Comment: @MichaelMaliszesky you beat me to it but yeah I'm glad to help. :) good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

A homeomorphism needs to be a map **from a space to another**, not a map from the topology of one space to the topology of another.

That is, if $(X,\mathscr{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{T}_Y)$ are topological spaces, a homeomorphism should be a **pointwise map** be a map $g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ satisfying the properties you listed above. You have used instead a map $g\colon \mathscr{T}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{T}_Y$. Note that the latter requires a topology of topology to begin talking about continuity.

Comment: Can you give an example of a pointwise map. And I think I do not get the difference between a "SET", "TOPOLOGY" and  a "SPACE".  I was under impression that a topology of a set *IS* a space.

Comment: In your example, $X=\{1,2,3\}$ is the space and $\mathscr{T}_1$ and $\mathscr{T}_2$ are two possible topologies for it. $g\colon X\rightarrow X$ defined by $g(1)=2$, $g(2)=3$, and $g(3)=1$ is a pointwise map.

Comment: I would recommend an introduction to simple (nonaxiomatic) set theory before you get into topology. Doing some real analysis (with metric spaces) before topology might be helpful too, since topology is a generalization of metric spaces.

Comment: I did a under grad. class in real analysis already (culminating in proving the fundamental theorem of calculus), and when there are metrics involved things make more sense to me. In analysis we Dealt with sets, not spaces, and i'm not "getting" the difference. In this example, there isn't a metric, and I'm having trouble .

Comment: In real analysis, the space is $\mathbb{R}$, and the topology is defined by taking all open balls generated by the metric $d$ defined by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Comment: its this **NON-METRIC** space that i'm having trouble with.

Comment: A topology $\mathscr{T}$ defines the open sets (i.e., if $U\subset X$ is said to be open in the topological space $(X,\mathscr{T})$ if and only if $U\in\mathscr{T}$). A metric $d$ on $X$ does not directly define what an open set is, but can be turned into a topology $\mathscr{T}_d$ as 
$$\mathscr{T}_{d}=\{U\subset X\colon\text{for each }u\in U\text{, there is an }r>0\text{ such that }B_{r}(u)\subset U\}.$$ I am using $B_r(p)$ to denote the open ball around $p$ of radius $r$. Now, a function is continuous in $(X,d)$ if and only if it is continuous in $(X,\mathscr{T}_d)$.

Comment: but without a metric, what is a radius? Because the shape of a ball depends on the metric.

Comment: A topology *does not* even need to be metrizable (turned into a metric space), I was just telling you what topology is induced by a metric. Put simply, metric implies topology, but topology does not imply metric.