# Verify if this is correct idea of continuous and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839292/question-about-definition-of-homeomorphism-counter-example/1839297?noredirect=1#comment3761105_1839297). My main motivation is to understand these defintions:

Definition of homeomorphism:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ is a bijective map $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ such that both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are continuous.

Definition of continuous:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be continuous if for every open subset $U \subseteq Y$, its preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

I think I'm finally starting to get this, I just want to verify that everything below is correct.

Let: $X = \{ 1,2,3 \}$

 $\mathscr{T}_1=\{X,\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$;

 $\mathscr{T}_2=\{X,\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,3\}\}$;

 $\mathscr{T}_3=\{X,\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$;

I know that $(X,\mathscr{T}_1)$ and  $(X,\mathscr{T}_2)$ are homeomorphic, there must exist a function $f$ that satisfies the above definition of continuous (and homeomorphism), But what would this function be?

Would it be this?

$f:(X,\mathscr{T}_1)  \rightarrow  (X,\mathscr{T}_2)$ 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 x & f(x) \\ \hline \hline
 1 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 3 \\ \hline
 3 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Now if I try to use the same $f$ to map from $(X,\mathscr{T}_1)$ to $(X,\mathscr{T}_3)$, then $f^{-1}(\{2,3\})= \{3,2\}$ and $\{3,2\} \notin \mathscr{T}_1$, so does that mean: 

$f:(X,\mathscr{T}_1)  \rightarrow  (X,\mathscr{T}_2)$ is continuous

$f:(X,\mathscr{T}_1)  \rightarrow  (X,\mathscr{T}_3)$ is not continuous

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: The "point" of a homeomorphism is that the two topological structures are,essentially, the same. As if we had a space of "green"  points and decided to color them red.... There are also many equivalent  topological def'ns of continuity and it is useful to know them all.

Comment: Great! I'm finally starting to understand this stuff!

Comment: Your toy example also illustrates an important point: continuity depends on the topologies involved, not necessarily just the sets used.